# unable to install R github packages with devtools (curl Timeout error)

Tags: r, ubuntu, dns, installation, devtools

I'm currently unable to install R github packages using devtools. I get the same error no matter which github package I try to install. Here's one example.

```
devtools::install_github("clauswilke/ggtextures")
```

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = h) :    Timeout was
>   reached: Resolving timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Is this an issue with R or my local home WiFi? Local home WiFi has been acting weird although I am able to post this and watch YouTube videos. If I type in a new website address Chrome sometimes takes 5-10 seconds before the site appears. Then it's blazing fast from that point on. Strange.

This sounds like a DNS issue? Maybe? Something else? Where do I even begin?

***[EDIT]*** I'm trying @hrbrmstr suggestion which is shown below. So do I juat change to OpenDNS to solve this issue? If that's the best solution I will and report back. Thank you for the help and I think it will educate some on more of R's tool. Definite upvote from me.

OS = Ubuntu 18.04

```
# docall(...)
                        host user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child          result
2                 github.com     0.004    0.004  15.007          0         0  192.30.253.112
21         stackoverflow.com     0.003    0.000   5.005          0         0  151.101.193.69
3                 google.com     0.000    0.000   0.040          0         0   172.217.15.78
4                  yahoo.com     0.001    0.000   0.040          0         0     72.30.35.10
5  www.this-wont-resolve.com     0.003    0.001   0.267          0         0           Error
6                  cisco.com     0.001    0.000   0.041          0         0    72.163.4.185
7          bankofamerica.com     0.002    0.000   5.005          0         0 171.159.228.150
8                  apple.com     0.000    0.003   5.005          0         0   17.142.160.59
9              microsoft.com     0.001    0.001   5.003          0         0      40.76.4.15
10              curl.haxx.se     0.001    0.000   0.061          0         0  151.101.250.49
```

.

```
# pingr::ping(...)
ping: bad linger time.
                  [,1] [,2] [,3]
github.com          NA   NA   NA
stackoverflow.com   NA   NA   NA
google.com          NA   NA   NA
yahoo.com           NA   NA   NA
cisco.com           NA   NA   NA
time.apple.com      NA   NA   NA
```

.

```
# install.packages("speedtest")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘speedtest’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)
```

Comment: Looks like your DNS resolution is broken on your machine or on your network.

Comment: @Flimzy When I call my ISP what do I even ask or tell them to get this fixed? I know the initial tech is going to read a script to me. I'll elevate the call but don't know what to say next. Any advice?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no advice. Internet troubleshooting is off-topic here.

Comment: As a temporary solution how do I increase the timeout?

Comment: Internet troubleshooting, even for temporary solutions, is off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(This won't solve your problem so it technically isn't an answer but it's also too long for a comment…SO pedants can feel free to downvote)*

While SO is not an internet connection tech support forum, we *can* give you some R tools to triage your connection.

I know have the `curl` package installed since you are trying to use `devtools` so give this a go:

```
do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(
    c(
      "github.com", "stackoverflow.com", "google.com", "yahoo.com",
      "www.this-wont-resolve.com", "cisco.com", "bankofamerica.com",
      "apple.com", "microsoft.com", "curl.haxx.se"
    ), 
    function(x) {
      clock <- system.time(res <- try(curl::nslookup(x), silent = TRUE), gcFirst = FALSE)
      clock <- as.list(clock)
      clock <- c(host = x, clock, result = if (inherits(res, "character")) res else "Error")
      clock
    }
  )
)
```

On my system ^^ produces:

```
##                         host user.self sys.self elapsed user.child sys.child          result
## 2                 github.com     0.000    0.000   0.001          0         0  192.30.253.113
## 21         stackoverflow.com     0.001    0.000   0.001          0         0   151.101.65.69
## 3                 google.com     0.000    0.000   0.001          0         0  172.217.10.142
## 4                  yahoo.com     0.000    0.001   0.001          0         0      72.30.35.9
## 5  www.this-wont-resolve.com     0.071    0.002   0.073          0         0           Error
## 6                  cisco.com     0.000    0.000   0.001          0         0    72.163.4.185
## 7          bankofamerica.com     0.001    0.000   0.000          0         0 171.159.228.150
## 8                  apple.com     0.000    0.001   0.001          0         0   17.142.160.59
## 9              microsoft.com     0.001    0.000   0.001          0         0  40.113.200.201
## 10              curl.haxx.se     0.000    0.000   0.001          0         0  151.101.118.49
```

What it is doing is using your operating system's resolver libraries to make DNS lookups the way `curl` does (and hence `httr`/`rvest` and the `devtools` network-based installers). You can get timings and also see if there are errors. There is a deliberate host that doesn't resolve in the provided list. Feel free to add more.

That should give you an idea of whether there are issues with resolving in general.

If you have `pingr` installed, you can do:

```
t(sapply(
  c(
    "github.com", "stackoverflow.com", "google.com", 
    "yahoo.com", "cisco.com", "time.apple.com"
  ),
  function(x) {
    res <- try(pingr::ping(destination = x, count = 3, timeout = 5))
  }
))
```

which, on my system, returns:

```
##                      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
## github.com         30.095 23.964 31.652
## stackoverflow.com  16.524 13.529 20.790
## google.com         30.743 22.004 22.333
## yahoo.com          34.450 33.070 40.198
## cisco.com          67.215 74.290 96.568
## time.apple.com    110.832 88.482 87.582
```

That should give you a basic idea of how well basic network ops to the internet are going. Super high values are bad.

If you have [`speedtest`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/speedtest/) installed, you can do:

```
speedtest::spd_test()
```

from an R console or:

```
Rscript -e 'speedtest::spd_test()'
```

from a command-line/terminal prompt and it'll give you output like:

```
## Gathering test configuration information...
## Gathering server list...
## Determining best server...
## Initiating test from Comcast Cable (###.###.###.###) to Otelco (Portland, ME)
## 
## Analyzing download speed..........
## Download: 166 Mbit/s
## 
## Analyzing upload speed......
## Upload: 7 Mbit/s
```

(yes, we have horribad internet in rural Maine)

I can post some more troubleshooting info later. Knowing what OS you use would be helpful.

NOTE: that some of the behvaviour you're describing is indicative of numerous malware strains that hijack DNS on systems (which is another reason I'm trying to help).

Comment: should I just change to OpenDNS or maybe Google DNS? I updated my question to include the info you recommended. Thank you.

Comment: The GitHub repo for `speedtest` has no mention of it being on CRAN. DNS seems to be fine (resolution and speed). Nothing seems to be hijacking your DNS either. Anything else I would be doing is in the "has nothing to do with R programming" so I'm not sure there's much else that I could suggest beyond "reboot" and then call comcast if things are still busted (and pray they know about linux systems)